# Generic Binary Search in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Below is my Generic Binary Search. It works okay with the integers type array (it finds all the elements in it). But the problem arises when I use a string array to find any string data. It runs okay for the first index and last index elements but I can't find the middle elements.

```
Stringarray = new string[] { "b", "a", "ab", "abc", "c" };

public static void BinarySearch<T>(T[] array, T searchFor, Comparer<T> comparer) {

        int high, low, mid;
        high = array.Length - 1;
        low = 0;
        if (array[0].Equals(searchFor))            
            Console.WriteLine("Value {0} Found At Index {1}",array[0],0);
        else if (array[high].Equals(searchFor))
            Console.WriteLine("Value {0} Found At Index {1}", array[high], high);
        else
        {
            while (low <= high)
            {
                mid = (high + low) / 2;
                if (comparer.Compare(array[mid], searchFor) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value {0} Found At Index {1}", array[mid], mid);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (comparer.Compare(searchFor, array[mid]) > 0)
                        high = mid + 1;
                    else
                        low = mid + 1;
                }

            }
            if (low > high)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value Not Found In the Collection");
            }
        }                 
    }
```

Comment: If this isn't homework, you should use `Array.BinarySearch`.  If it is, you should tag it as such.  Also, you should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx)?

Comment: No there are not reasons for not using Array.BinarySearch. i want to know how things works at the back hand of that method. so by doing that i am working on this.

Comment: @Slaks i am found the problem but its quite odd and weird. if you change the expression of ( high = mid + 1 ) to (low = mid + 1 ) and (high = mid - 1) it works ok for the string array. but that wont work for int Type ARRAY :S

Comment: pst: Maybe he needs to pass in an `IList<T>` instead of `T[]`

Answer (score 23):

A binary search **requires that the input be sorted**. How is "b, a, ab, abc, c" sorted? It does not appear to be sorted on any obvious sort key. If you are trying to search unsorted data you should be using a hash set, not a binary search on a list.

Also, your calculation of midpoint is subtly wrong because the addition of high + low can overflow. It then becomes a negative number, which is divided by two.

This is extremely unlikely for realistically-sized arrays but it is entirely possible that you'll want to use this algorithm someday for data types that support indexing with large integers, like a memory-mapped file of sorted data.

The best practice for writing a binary search algorithm is to do `(high - low) / 2 + low` when calculating the midpoint, because that stays in range the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines are suspect:

```
high = mid + 1
low = mid + 1
```

Hmm. Look at the offsets. Of course this is well documented [Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on Wikipedia. You also do extra work. Examine the pseudo-code and examples closely.

Answer (score 1):

pst Your advice really worked. :) this code is working for both int and string.

```
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(T[] array, T searchFor, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int high, low, mid;
        high = array.Length - 1;
        low = 0;
        if (array[0].Equals(searchFor))
            return 0;
        else if (array[high].Equals(searchFor))
            return high;
        else
        {
            while (low <= high)
            {                   
                mid = (high + low) / 2;
                if (comparer.Compare(array[mid], searchFor) == 0)                   
                    return mid;                    
                else if (comparer.Compare(array[mid], searchFor) > 0)                    
                    high = mid - 1;                    
                else                    
                    low = mid + 1;                  
            }
            return -1;                
        }                 
    }
```

Comment: The compare method is unnecessarily invoked twice.

Answer (score 1):

//Binary search recursive method

```
    public void BinarySearch(int[] input,int key,int start,int end)
    {
        int index=-1;
        int mid=(start+end)/2;
        if (input[start] <= key && key <= input[end])
        {
            if (key < input[mid])
                BinarySearch(input, key, start, mid);
            else if (key > input[mid])
                BinarySearch(input, key, mid + 1, end);
            else if (key == input[mid])
                index = mid;
            if (index != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("got it at " + index);
        }
    }  

     int[] input4 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };   
     BinarySearch(input4, 1, 0, 8);
```