# C#: Efficient big array loop

Tags: performance, optimization

I had to solve a problem where I had to loop through an int array with a non-fixed size to check if the array contains a given number. This array is always sorted by ascending.

So, this problem is not that big of a deal to solve. I created a simple for loop that would return true if it found the number. But the problem stated that the array could have a length of one million elements (you could get extra points if it was optimized for this kind of array). This is where I had a hard time to think of something.

What I tried to do was to get the middle element, check if the given number is lower or higher than the middle element, then change the start and end variable in the for loop to only contain one half. This would save some time, but in a one million big array it's still not that efficient.

It triggered me a bit to not know an efficient way (I didn't get the extra points), so I've been busy finding efficient ways of looping through a big array.

So here is my question: What are some efficient ways to loop through a big ass array?

Comment: You are already using bisection, I don't think it will get any better than that.

Comment: I confirm what @Adder says. By cutting in half the space you do what is called a Binary Search in other programming languages. As far as I know, the binary search is the fastest way to find something present in a sorted array. That way allows you to reduce the space on which you do the search. You can search on the internet information on Binary Search if you would like more information on that. For example you have information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067643/binary-search-of-a-sorted-array

Comment: @HpTerm So if im correct than what it does in the link you have provided is to 'loop' twice simultaneously from begin to mid and from end to mid. That's not that different than what I was doing, right? Or is this more efficient?

Comment: No, for me, all the loop is binary, you cut everything in half until you find the number you are searching for. If you reach a point where you cannot cut in half the last space you have means the number is not present. Look on wikipedia I think the explanation is clear enough. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Yes, I get it now! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Given that the distribution of the data is known, you can linearly interpolate the bisection point instead of always selecting the midpoint. This has marginally better than O(log N) behavior.