# Binary search of strings in an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Ok so I have been at this same error for about 18 hours and am totally lost. What I am trying to do is conduct a binary search where the search begins in the middle of the array and then eliminates half of the array everytime by comparing the term that was searched for to the middle term. So far my code is not producing errors except when I try to compare if the searched term is greater than the middle term. I know that I am trying to compare two strings and so greater than doesn't apply, but I have no idea how else to do it. Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string[] contacts = new string[20];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); //Clears the ListBox of all previous items

        if (!File.Exists("Week3List.txt")) //Verifies that the file exists
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to write the file first", "Validation", MessageBoxButton.OK); //Notifies the user if the file does not exist
            return;
        }
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Week3List.txt")) //Designates the path to the file that was created
        {
            try
            {
                contacts = File.ReadAllLines("Week3List.txt");
                Array.Sort(contacts);
                foreach (string contact in contacts)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(contact);
                }
                sr.Close(); //Closes the StreamReader
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //A catch to handle access errors
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception Handler", MessageBoxButton.OK); //Adds the error message to the ListBox
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bSearch(contacts);
    }

    private void bSearch(string[] contacts)
    {
        int index = Array.BinarySearch(contacts, textBox1.Text);
    }

    public int BinarySearch(string[] contacts, string searchTerm)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last = contacts.Length - 1;
        int position = -1;
        bool found = false;
        int compCount = 0;
        searchTerm = textBox1.Text;

        while (found != true && first <= last)
        {
            int middle = (first + last) / 2;

            if (contacts[middle] == searchTerm)
            {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
                compCount++;

                MessageBox.Show("Your search has been found after " + compCount + "comparisons.");
            }
            else if (contacts[middle] > searchTerm)
            {
                last = middle;
                compCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                first = middle;
                compCount++;
            }
        }
        return position;
        return compCount;
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone see where I am going wrong or know of a way to compare the two for a greater or less than value? I thought because it was sorted that it might compare the first letter and determine based off of that but I was wrong.

Comment: Are you doing a binary search on 20 items? Or is this just an example and the number of items is far far larger?

Comment: 2 `return` instruction continuously?? really?

Comment: The binary search is of 20 names read from a text file. As far as the 2 `return` instruction continuously comment I am not sure what you mean. Did I call a continuous `return` that I missed?

Comment: `return position;  
        return compCount;`

Comment: Oh right, nice catch. That has been corrected thank you.

Comment: see it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824811/4038978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this method for comparing strings.  It will tell you whether a string is greater, less, or equal (in value) to another string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: is this not a comment??

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>{"Apple", "Microsoft", "Yahoo", "StackOverflow" };
myList.Sort(); //Apple Microsoft StackOverflow Yahoo 
myList.BinarySearch("Yahoo"); // 3
```

Or if using `Array`:

```
string[] myArr = new string[]{"Apple", "Microsoft", "Yahoo", "StackOverflow" };
Array.Sort(myArr); //Apple Microsoft StackOverflow Yahoo 
Array.BinarySearch<string>(myArr, "Yahoo"); // 3
```

Comment: I doubt that's in the spirit of the homework exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright thank you to RegularExpression for the suggestion to look at a method for comparing strings. I changed the code

`if (contacts[middle] == searchTerm)` and `else if (contacts[middle] > searchTerm)`

to

`if (string.Compare(contacts[middle], searchTerm, true) == 0)` and `else if (string.Compare(contacts[middle], searchTerm, true) > 0)`

and it is now working perfectly! Thank you all for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried :

```
contacts.ToList().BinarySearch(searchTerm);
```

Comment: I thought about something like that but I have to have a counter for the number of comparisons made. That means I had to write the BinarySearch itself instead of using the auto generated one. (I think that is what you are suggesting) My issue is that in the BinarySearch method the else if comparison doesn't work because they are strings. Would converting it to a list instead of an Array help with that? I am still very new to C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a binary search on a string array this is the way to do it. You may want to choose a different Culture for the StringComparer.

```
string[] arr = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};

int k = Array.BinarySearch(arr,"d",StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this problem  without using built-in
Extension and Helper of programming language You Should do this : ( See the [online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MylWxQ))

> important: Your `Array` should be `sorted`  because the `Binarry-Search` is not  working on the `UnSorted` list.

```
 static int Find(string[] data, string SearachItem)
    {
        //It is mandatory to turn off case-sensitive by convert values to lowercase or uppercase
        ConvertArrayToLower(data); 
        string Lower = SearachItem.ToLower();
        
        //initiate
        char XChar = Lower[0]; // we will compare first char of Search Item by first char of array values
        int FirstIndex = 0;
        int LastIndex = data.Length - 1;
        while (FirstIndex <= LastIndex)
        {
            int MiddelIndex = (FirstIndex + LastIndex) / 2;
            char middel = data[MiddelIndex][0];
            if (XChar > middel)
                FirstIndex = MiddelIndex + 1;
            else if (XChar < middel)
                LastIndex = MiddelIndex - 1;
            else if (data[MiddelIndex] != Lower) // maybe the first char of two or more values will be the same so we should go to the next step
            {
                FirstIndex = MiddelIndex + 1;

            }
            else return MiddelIndex; // if found
        }

        //if not found
        return -1;
    }

    private static void ConvertArrayToLower(string[] data)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = data[i].ToLower();
        }
    }
```

> See the [online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MylWxQ)